# Why the source code is in single line ? CLion issue !! Need advice

Tags: clion

I am using CLion for C programming. The code is well aligned in the CLion editor, but when I see the source code file ( .c ) in the project directory. The code is in single line.

like this:-

## include int main() { printf("Hello"); return 0; }

how can I solve this problem, I tried all options in editor settings etc, but nothing happened. :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick guess not knowing CLion myself, maybe CLion uses unix line endings (LF) and the editor you use to look at the source file outside of CLion uses Windows line endings (CR/LF).

To solve the issue, figure out how to change the line endings in CLion to Windows style, or use an editor which automatically detects the correct line endings (e.g. Notepad++).

Update: According to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/configuring-line-separators.html), you can change the line ending format in CLion under Settings -> Code Style.